# Concatenating Two Different IEnumerable Objects in C#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have got two different IEnumerable objects, however properties are almost similar in both the classes,now I want to concatenate/merge them, so both the results can be assigned to repeater datasource, below is the sample code.

```
IEnumerable<ICachedItem> cacheOld = Cache<String>.CachedItems; //My Old Cache Class, here I am fetching all the cached Items
IEnumerable<Caching.ICachedItem> cacheNew = Caching.Cache<String>.CachedItems; //My New class to get the cached items   
var combined = cacheNew.Cast<ICachedItem>().Concat(cacheOld); //Trying to concat both
repeater.DataSource = combined.OrderBy(entry => entry.Region + ":" + entry.Prefix + ":" + entry.Key); //Assigning to Datasource
repeater.DataBind();
```

**combined** object is coming blank, any suggestions.

Update:
Currently we have got these in the class

```
public class CachedItem<T>: ICachedItem
{

    public CachedItem(String key, String prefix, T value)
        : this(CacheRegion.Site, prefix, key, value)
    {
    }    
}
```

Do we need to modify this class?

Comment: `Cast<T>` does not magically change types of objects - if your new and old classes are not related you have to create new items for at least one of the types... Depending on actual goal implementing old interface on new type may be enough.

Comment: You are right Alex, what is the best way to do this...any suggestions.

Comment: No idea how you classes look like, so don't have a suggestion - Hadi Brais's answer is possible approach. Note that you don't need to post your exact code - go for for non-ambiguous code in post. Right now you have 2 interfaces (and possibly 2 classes) with the same names and expect one magically to figure out how they relate (or even which one you are talking about).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Select` to convert new items to old items. Assuming you have the appropriate constructor, you can do this:

```
var combined = cacheNew.Select(newItem => new OldCachedItem(newItem)).Concat(cacheOld);
```

The result would be of type `IEnumerable<ICachedItem>`. You should replace `OldCachedItem` with name of the old cached item type that implements `ICachedItem`.

Comment: thanks Hadi...What need to be added to replace OldCachedItem

Comment: @ram What is the name of the type that implements `ICachedItem` used in the first line of your code snippet?

Comment: it is internal class CachedItem<T>: ICachedItem, However giving exception for overloading.

Comment: @ram It should be then `var combined = cacheNew.Select(newItem => new CachedItem<String>(newItem)).Concat(cacheOld);` You have to define a constructor in `CachedItem<T>` that accepts `Caching.ICachedItem` to be converted. What type of exception is thrown?

Comment: I have added the sample code of my class in my question...what you are asking to do over there?